# Не выполняются rake задачи и методы в whenever

Tags: ruby, cron

Доброго времени суток!

Пробую запустить rake задачи и классовые методы используя gem whenever, в `schedule.rb` следующее:

```
every 30.minutes do
  runner "User.remove_highlight"
end
```

этот же метод пробовал переносить в rake задачу, и вызывать в `schedule.rb`:

```
every 30.minutes do
  rake "remove_highlight"
end
```

Перед тем, как использовать метод, проверил его работоспособность, добавлял его в `ApplicationController` и вызывал `before_filter`, но, чтобы не нагружать обработку страниц, целесообразно вынести это в `schedule.rb` и вызывать в определенное время. Все выполнял в соответствии с документацией, но методы не отрабатывают на локалке. Также, как удалось прочитать, на Mac OS залезть в логи гема достаточно непросто. Использую gem в первый раз, поэтому прошу помощи у опытных, кто может сталкивался с данной проблемой. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Насколько я знаю Whenever запускается в виде задачи при деплое. И задача Whenever - добавление/обновление задач в crontab. Whenever не запускается в виде процесса и не запускает таски.

Comment: ^ Это действительно так. Создать расписание мало, нужно его ещё и записать в систему. Смотрите вывод `whenever --help` на предмет деталей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) всего лишь интерфейс к демону-планирвщику [cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).
После того как вы добавили инструкцию в `config/schedule.rb` 
и выполнили `whenever --update-crontab` гем обновит файл крона. 
Все текущие задания можно посмотреть командой `crontab -l`.

`grep CRON /var/log/syslog` покажет логи крона.

PS: Если же вам необходимы отложенные задачи, обратите внимание на [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).